# Using ADFS 2.0 for Google apps single sign on

Tags: active-directory, g-suite, single-sign-on, adfs

Microsoft Active Directory Federation Services 2.0 has been recently released, and it has passed [interoperability tests](http://blogs.msdn.com/interoperability/archive/2009/09/30/saml-2-0-interoperability-testing-passed.aspx) for SAML 2.0.

Does this mean that is can be used to authenticate users of Google Apps which also uses [SAML](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60224)?

Has anyone successfully setup Google apps with ADFS 2.0 for single sign on?

If you have gotten it to work please tell us what is required to get this working?

To put it another way, does someone have a good HOWTO for using ADFS 2.0 and Google Apps together?  I was not able to find anything through a search of the web.

Answer (score 1):

I have got this working - Google Apps Single Sign-on, ADFS and a custom STS (although you could easily use Windows Auth or some other STS downstream, it doesn't affect the Google/ADFS configuration).

I have documented the steps required on my blog:

http://www.huggill.com/2012/01/12/setting-up-google-apps-single-sign-on-sso-with-adfs-2-0-and-a-custom-sts-such-as-identityserver/

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that there are no simple How-to steps to configuring SSO. If you look at this diagram it shows the authentication process. You would need an custom web application on your side to to interact with ADFS. When you configure it from the Google Apps CPanel you give it a Sign-in, Sign-out, & password change urls and a public key certificate is also required.

http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/sso/saml_reference_implementation.html

There are many 3rd Party tools that could assist in the Google Apps Marketplace. http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/search?orderBy=rating&query=saml